# Composer Adds ... in Eloquent Classes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, composer-php

I install Laravels Eloquent outside the laravel enviroment like so...

```
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "psr/log": "^1.0",
    "setasign/fpdi": "1.6.*",
    "illuminate/database": "*"
},
```

Then I did `composer install`

It works great locally but when I put it on the server I get a error

`syntax error, unexpected '.'`

For some reason when the classes were imported, they were imported with alot of classes looking like this

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    return $this->newQuery()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

They add `...` to alot of the magic method calls. Nothing breaks on my machine locally but the server does not like this. what is up with this ??

if I remove them then the ORM stops working altogether

Comment: What version of PHP are you using on the server? That's a variadic operator that was introduced in 5.6. [src](http://php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: The version is  5.5.17 . I am trying to look for a older version of eloquent

Comment: It looks like Laravel only started requiring 5.6.* as of version 5.3 ([5.2 only needed 5.5.9](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements)) so if you can find what version of eloquent Laravel 5.2 was using, you should be able to use that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` or the `splat` operator was introduced in PHP 5.6. The server probably has an older version of PHP.

[PHP 5.6 "new features" notes.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

EDIT:

To further answer your question, Eloquent 5.2.* only required PHP >= 5.5.9, so you should be able to use [the latest 5.2 release](https://github.com/illuminate/database/releases/tag/v5.2.45).

Comment: You are right. The version is  5.5.17. Would you happen to know which version works for 5.5 ?

Comment: @numerical25 All the illuminate components use the same version numbers as the Laravel framework so `5.2.*` should work for you.

Comment: 5.2.* seems still a little older. The server has PHP 5.5.17

Comment: @numerical25 `5.3.0` requires `"php": ">=5.6.4",` .  https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/v5.3.0/composer.json